# Add a default value for existing Image alt field

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I have an image field in article content type and have created hundreds of nodes for article content type, but now I need to add a value for image alt fields for these existing nodes.
Even the default value field for image alt is not showing when I try to edit the field.

How can I add values for the alt attribute of the image field in existing nodes?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a node_preprocess function to your theme file. The logic would be to check if the current node has a value in the field for "image alt text", if not then set a default value, else return.

These are not the exact field names but this should get you started on what to look for in your code.

```
 function MYTHEME_preprocess_article(&$variables) {
      if (!field_image_alt_text->getValue().strlen() = 0 || null ) { set value to something } else {return;}
};
```

Comment: Hi @ssa4b, where I need to add this code? I'm new to Drupal and don't know the Drupal development.

Comment: In your template.php file. In your '/sites/all/themes/<custom theme folder>' if you're using a custom theme.

Comment: it says `syntax error: unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`